# How to add password to Excel file in Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpspreadsheet, laravel-excel

I am learning Laravel Framework. I like to know if there is a package or tool that automatically adds or insert password into Excel file in Laravel application so that registered user can open the file with password known to the user only after downloading it.

Comment: try phpoffice/phpspreadsheet  ?

Comment: No please. I will try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add [`maatwebsite/excel`](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) package for Laravel which is a wrapper around [`phpoffice/phpspreadsheet`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) package.

Here is the docs on how to set security on a spreadsheet on [*PhpSpreadsheet*](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#setting-security-on-a-spreadsheet):
https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#setting-security-on-a-spreadsheet

See [extending section](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/extending.html) of the *laravel-excel* documentations to learn how to call *PhpSpreadsheet* methods on a event or using a macro.

The final code would be something like this:

```php
namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeExport;

class InvoicesExport implements WithEvents
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            BeforeExport::class  => function(BeforeExport $event) {
                $event->writer->getDelegate()->getSecurity()->setLockWindows(true);
                $event->writer->getDelegate()->getSecurity()->setLockStructure(true);
                $event->writer->getDelegate()->getSecurity()->setWorkbookPassword("Your password");
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay many thanks. I will try to implement this package tomorrow.

Comment: Not working in my case. The file is not protected and I can still open the exported file and edit anything i likes

Comment: In my case did not work but at the above solution I have added AfterSheet event to work like so:
return [
           ...
            AfterSheet::class => function (AfterSheet $event){
                 ...
                 $event->sheet->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
            },

            BeforeExport::class => function(BeforeExport $event){ ... }
]